# Javascript / sharepoint : Trying to get input values returns only default values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm working on a Visual Webpart which is composed with a form which calls an Ajax function.

here is an example of my fields :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ProjectCode" runat="server" Width="100%"/>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ProjectStatus" runat="server" Width="100%"/>
```

Thoses fields are Databinded on a datatable (and an empty field is inserted at the first index) in code behind.
I try to get their values by this javascript ( Using native javascript or JQuery ):

```
var pjcodejq = $('#<%=ProjectCode.ClientID%>').attr('value');
var pjcodejq1 = $('#<%=ProjectCode.ClientID%>').val();
var pjcode = document.getElementById('<%=ProjectCode.ClientID%>').value;

var pjstatusjq = $('#<%=ProjectStatus.ClientID%>').attr('value');
var pjstatusjq1 = $('#<%=ProjectStatus.ClientID%>').val();
var pjstatus = document.getElementById('<%=ProjectStatus.ClientID%>').value;
```

None of these examples return value except if i bind the fields with a default value, but if i modify this value it will only return the default one.

Event is triggered by :

```
$('#submitSearch').unbind('click').click(function () {
```

On this field

```
<button id="submitSearch">Search</button>
```

Any advice / solution is welcome.

Comment: When are you executing the JS function to load the values? I think there must be the problem because if the <asp:TextBox generated a <input field and you are accessing it with the ClientID I don't see why it should not return the actual value of the field.

Comment: I've edited the question with event (but the event works well). How you suggest to access to the field instead of using clientID?

Comment: No, accessing the field with clientID is perfectly fine! I post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the problem is that you submit the form while reading the values.

Try to add `type="button"` to your button so it is no more a submit button by default.

Comment: I'll try this, and trigg my event on submit. Give you feedbacks ASAP.

Comment: No worries! Or just call the function per console or whatever just to make sure it works.

Comment: Now i got an issue with my jquery event. Was doing an Unbind to prevent the javascript to call it twice, but now it submits the form twice. First with good values and second with default :/

Comment: Why are you submitting the form at all? What is "the bigger picture", what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution found with @CoolGadgetsForGeeks advices.

Use this javascript event :

```
$('form').submit(function () {
```

And replace button with

```
<input type="submit" id="submitSearch" style="width:100%"/>
```

And finally add a return false at the end of my javascript function.